# Можно ли из дека указателей применить к ним delete без использования for и будет ли это быстрее?

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть ли способ из деков указателей

```
    deque<T*> allotted, exempted;
```

Применить к указателям внутри дека delete без использования цикла for?

```
    for (auto& a : allotted) { //O(Q)
        delete a;
    }
    for (auto& a : exempted) { //O(Q)
        delete a;
    }
```

Comment: Итератор на 1 элемент? Только если вы не используете свой аллокатор. Но зачем вам это?

Comment: Не, с первым элементом пытался, не получилось. Да поупражняться решил, нашел задачку, сделал, захотел пооптимизировать и вот подумал, можно ли этот цикл как-то оптимизировать. :)

Comment: Можно выделять память блоками, кратными sizeof(T) (поправьте меня если ересь). И в деке хранить смещения внутри одного большого блока, заведомо вмещающего все возможные размеры дека. А удалить потом сразу весь блок. Но это уже больше на slub аллокатор похоже.

Comment: Опечатался - slab [аллокатор](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation). [Оригинальная статья](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/cs194-24/hand-outs/bonwick_slab.pdf). Но это уже уровень ОС, так что быстрее и правда вряд-ли получится.

Comment: Храните в них `std::unique_ptr<T>`, тогда объекты будут удаляться при подчисте контейнера

Comment: @VTT а это не то же самое что просто в цикле их удалить? По времени выполнения.

Comment: @vegorov То же самое. Но если у вас было создано n объектов посредством new, то должно быть и соответственно n вызовов delete. А вот писать цикл for и самостоятельно вызывать delete - это лишнее.

Comment: Что бы удаление отрабатывало быстро, нужно что бы его не было. Если память выделять скопом, то можно и удалять скопом. memory pool  в помощь

Comment: @VTT да это понятно, просто речь шла вроде про ускорение процесса удаления выделенной памяти

Comment: @vegorov Даже если ускорять процесс удаления выделенной памяти, то от вызова n деструкторов для сферических объектов типа T никак не избавиться.

Comment: если не будет конструкторов-деструторов, то не будет и кого вызывать

Comment: @VTT если это пользовательский тип, а не обычный типа double или int

Comment: @KoVadim про memory pool - а сама ОС не делает чего-то подобного ? Не поддерживает набор заранее выделенной памяти и не отдают пользователю ? Например buddy + slab аллокатор. Ну в смысле memory pool прям действительно что-то ускорит ?

Comment: @vegorov Мне кажется вы какую-ту свою задачу придумываете. В оригинальном посте как раз некоторый пользовательский тип, и даже если это оказался бы int или double от вызова delete n раз никуда не деться. А соптимизировать можно просто сразу выделив блок хранимых объектов T[] и удаляя его одним `delete[]`.

Comment: @VTT Через delete[] я тоже сначала подумал, но проблема в том, что размер блока изначально неизвестен и добавляется туда указатель во время работы программы

Comment: @vegorov если использовать только **простые типы** (то есть, `int`, `char[размер]`) и выделять память один раз большим куском и потом просто разместить массив объектов в нем через placement new (или прямо так закастовать, но аккуратно), то деструктор как таковой не нужен будет. Только память почистить один раз. Но только зачем все это? это оправдано в играх, в высоконагруженных приложениях, когда другие оптимизации уже выкручены на максимум.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае (а похоже, что у вас именно такой обобщенный, судя по `T*`) для каждого указателя должен быть вызван деструктор. А все указатели указывают в общем случае в разные несмежные места.

Так что обмануть не удастся. Разве что завершить программу, а там вся память сама освободится, а деструкторы уже никого интересовать не будут...